# JSON works Locally but not with Servers

Tags: json

Here is my little first project as practice, having real trouble figuring out how to use JSON, took me a while to get it work locally but still no luck with servers, and tried few a including one i hosted, and even tried it with other hosted json files.

http://jsfiddle.net/Atlas_/Mgyc5/1/

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
async: false,
url: "package.json", //https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmw63i4v7dtnx6t/package.json
'success': function (json) {
    theQuiz = json.quiz;
    console.log(json);
    console.log(theQuiz);

}
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're being blocked by the browser's [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Unless you're using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) it'll never work unless your AJAX comes from the same server as your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access another domain be carefully with "Crossdomain".

To use with dropbox, try changing the URL to:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fmw63i4v7dtnx6t/package.json

Your code will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fmw63i4v7dtnx6t/package.json", 
    success: function (json) {
        theQuiz = json.quiz;
        console.log(json);
        console.log(theQuiz);

    }
});
```

When you request 'dl.dropboxusercontent.com', you have this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control

> "In this case, the server responds with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
>   *  which means that the resource can be accessed by any domain in  a cross-site manner."

Another options: Some websites (twitter, for example) work with "jsonp". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP or ..you can create your own proxy.

Comment: I read about proxy,jsonp,cors and looks like cors is the way to go. I don't know how you got the dl.dropboxusercontent part, if dropbox has Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * enabled shouldn't the first link work too? I am definitely looking into it further.